# How to find the specific numbers in a list with a sum of a particular sum with Python

Tags: python

I have a list of numbers:

```
[40.5, 19.04, 31.72, 68.16, 45.68, 45.68, 532.74, 137.52, 401.58, 25.92, 185.90, 1037.96, 23.41, 829.50, 98.35, 57.12, 620.87, 21, 435.08, 460.85, 1079.16, 1386.29, 272.82, 131.44, 135.51, 39, 1079.16, 230.63, 1297.44, 301.27, 372.57,173.17, 191.84, 213.92, 423.9, 56.24, 189.98, 14.76]
```

And I have a sum of some specific numbers in the list, how do I get the numbers with a sum of the known sum?

For example, if it's known that the sum is 59.04, how do I find out the 40.5 and 19.04?

Cheers!

Comment: Is it always a sum of two numbers?

Comment: Can you also please put down - your attempt ?

Comment: When you say the number x is a sum of some numbers. Is it guaranteed to be a sum of 2 numbers or could it be sum of n numbers? For eg. is 70 supposed to be sum of 30 and 40 or it could be 20+20+20+5+3+2?

Comment: Is the sum value always possible?

Comment: @Chris yes! It should be always possible

Comment: @Harsh yes, it can be sum of n numbers.

Comment: @vbn sorry I have no idea about how to deal with this problem at all, and I am currently in a auditing team, my manager is asking me to do so. Sorry if it bothers you

Comment: an algorithm or python code?

Comment: @SandrinJoy preferably a python code:)))

Answer (score 0):

Use this to find a sum pair

```
def findPair(A, sum):
    for i in range(len(A) - 1):# consider each element except last element
        for j in range(i + 1, len(A)):# start from i'th element till last element
            if A[i] + A[j] == sum:# if desired sum is found, print it and return
                print("Pair found at index", i, "and", j)
                print("Sum Pair:", A[i], A[j])
                return
    print("Pair not found")# No pair with given sum exists in the list
 
 
A = [40.5, 19.04, 31.72, 68.16, 45.68, 45.68, 532.74, 137.52, 401.58, 25.92, 185.90, 1037.96, 23.41, 829.50, 98.35, 57.12, 620.87, 21, 435.08, 460.85, 1079.16, 1386.29, 272.82, 131.44, 135.51, 39, 1079.16, 230.63, 1297.44, 301.27, 372.57,173.17, 191.84, 213.92, 423.9, 56.24, 189.98, 14.76]

findPair(A, 59.54)
sum = 99.88
findPair(A, sum)
```

Output:

```
Pair found at index 0 and 1
Sum Pair: 40.5 19.04
Pair found at index 2 and 3
Sum Pair: 31.72 68.16
```

Reference: https://www.techiedelight.com/find-pair-with-given-sum-array/

Sum for N Numbers:

```
import itertools
def findlist(A, summ):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in itertools.combinations(A, i):
            res = round(sum(list(j)), 2) 
            if res == summ:
                print("Sum Combinations", j )
A = [40.5, 19.04, 31.72, 68.16, 45.68]
findlist(A, 91.26)
```

Note:This will be slower for Large Lists

Comment: As asked in the question, the sum can be of n numbers and not just 2 numbers.

Comment: Added a Code for N Numbers but it will be slow for a large list @Harsh

Answer (score 0):

```
is_sum = lambda seq, x: any(x == y + z for yi, y in enumerate(seq) for zi, z in enumerate(seq) if zi != yi)
```

```
>>> is_sum([40.5, 19.04, 31.72, 68.16, 45.68, 45.68, 532.74, 137.52, 401.58, 25.92, 185.90, 1037.96, 23.41, 829.50, 98.35, 57.12, 620.87, 21, 435.08, 460.85, 1079.16, 1386.29, 272.82, 131.44, 135.51, 39, 1079.16, 230.63, 1297.44, 301.27, 372.57,173.17, 191.84, 213.92, 423.9, 56.24, 189.98, 14.76], 59.04)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use itertools,

```
import itertools
listofnumbers = [40.5, 19.04, 31.72, 68.16, 45.68, 45.68, 532.74, 137.52, 401.58, 25.92, 185.90, 1037.96, 23.41, 829.50, 98.35, 57.12, 620.87, 21, 435.08, 460.85, 1079.16, 1386.29, 272.82, 131.44, 135.51, 39, 1079.16, 230.63, 1297.44, 301.27, 372.57,173.17, 191.84, 213.92, 423.9, 56.24, 189.98, 14.76]
target = 59.54
for numbers in itertools.combinations(listofnumbers,2):
    if round(sum(numbers),2) == target:
        print(numbers)
```

specify 2 numbers, your output will be

```
(40.5, 19.04)
```